# Why are my attempts at using Vimeo's advanced API authentication using Perl's Net::OAuth failing?

Tags: perl, oauth, vimeo

I have tried two different approach to do vimeo advanced api authentication. Please find below both:-

**1st Approach:**

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::HMAC_SHA1;
use Data::Dump qw /dump/;
use URI::Escape;
use Net::OAuth;
use MIME::Base64;
use LWP::UserAgent;

# Authorize a user

my $consumer_key = "CONSUMERKEY";
my $secret       = "SECRET";
my $method       = "vimeo.videos.search" ;
my $oauth_nonce  = int( rand( 2**32 ) ) ;
my $timestamp    = time ;
my $query        = "happy" ;
my $url          = "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2/" ;

my $str =   "method=$method&oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key&oauth_nonce=$oauth_nonce&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=$timestamp&oauth_version=1.0&query=$query";

$str = uri_escape( $str) ;
$url = uri_escape( $url) ;

my $secret_key = $secret . '&';
my $base_str   = "GET" . "&" . $url . "&" . $str ;

my $hmac = Digest::HMAC_SHA1->new( $secret_key ) ;
$hmac->add($base_str) ;

my $oauth_signature = $hmac->b64digest ;
$oauth_signature    = encode_base64($oauth_signature );
chomp $oauth_signature;
$oauth_signature    =  uri_escape( $oauth_signature );

my $v_search_url = "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2? method=$method&oauth_consumer_key=$key&oauth_nonce=$oauth_nonce&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=$timestamp&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=$oauth_signature&query=$query" ;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res     = $browser->get( $v_search_url );
print $res->content;

The response content throws following error:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp generated_in="0.0024" stat="fail">
    <err code="401" expl="The consumer key passed was not valid." msg="Invalid consumer key"/>
</rsp>
```

The consumer key used above is a valid one (Not shared though on top). On hitting the above search url directly on mozilla browser throws this error: "The oauth_signature passed was not valid."
Please let me know where exactly the code is having error. I have followed the oauth spec provided at: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth

**2nd Approach:**

```
#!perl                                                                                                                                          

use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::HMAC_SHA1;
use Data::Dump qw /dump/;
use URI::Escape;
use Net::OAuth;
use Net::OAuth::RequestTokenRequest;
use MIME::Base64;
use LWP::UserAgent;

# Authorize a user                                                                                                                                    
my $consumer_key = "CONSUMERKEY";
my $secret       = "SECRET";
my $method       = "vimeo.videos.search" ;
my $oauth_nonce  = int( rand( 2**32 ) ) ;
my $timestamp    = time ;
my $query        = "happy" ;
my $url          = "http://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token";

my $request = Net::OAuth::RequestTokenRequest->new(
    consumer_key     => $consumer_key,
    consumer_secret  => $secret,
    request_url      => $url,
    request_method   => 'GET',
    signature_method => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    timestamp        => $timestamp,
    nonce            => $oauth_nonce,
);

die "COULDN'T GET REQUEST SIGN! Check parameters.\n" unless $request->sign;
die "COULDN'T VERIFY! Check OAuth parameters.\n" unless $request->verify;

my $browser   = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $post_body = $request->to_post_body;
$post_body    = "oauth_callback=oob&" . $post_body;
my $post_url  = $url . '/?' . $post_body;

my $res       = $browser->get( $post_url );

die $res->status_line unless ($res->is_success);

print $res->content;
```

This method is also failing by throwing above error stating "401 Unauthorized" and while hitting the url on browser it throws the same 'Invalid oauth signature error'. Since this guy is throwing error on the first step of Net::Oauth I cannot proceed further. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: In your first approach, you have `use URI::Escape;"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2/"`

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, so I am posting it as an answer, but it really is not an answer (only tangentially related in that you are relying on the nonce as a security mechanism). However, the information is relevant, so I am making it a community wiki. HTH.

I noticed you have:

```
my $oauth_nonce  = int( rand( 2**32 ) ) ;
```

and you seem to be on Windows. You should not use the built in `rand` (which Perl takes from the C runtime) because of the following pitfall:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %counts;

for (1 .. 1_000_000) {
    $counts{ int( rand( 2**32 ) )}++;
}

print scalar keys %counts, "\n";
```

Output:

```
32768
```

For more information, see my blog post [Don't leave randomness to chance (or, avoid using rand if it matters)](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html).

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to compile your second script, I first got:

`Global symbol "$key" requires explicit package name at C:\temp\tt.pl line 24.`

After fixing that, I got:

`Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:/opt/Perl/site/lib/Net/OAuth/SignatureMethod/HMAC_SHA1.pm line 18.`
`COULDN'T VERIFY! Check OAuth parameters.`

I cannot do a live test because I don't have anything set up to access the Vimeo API, but the warning from `Net::OAuth::SignatureMethod::HMAC_SHA1` indicates that there is probably another typo in there somewhere.

It looks like you actually need to sign your request after creating it:

```
$request->sign;
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo's. Now, I have corrected the same. I have tried multiple options but not getting any success. I have also tried to do a consumer request but that also fails stating the same oauth signature invalid error.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach you have used my `$oauth_signature = $hmac->b64digest;`
instead of `$hmac->b64digest` use `$hmac->digest`, it will work.